# How to scroll all the sprites in cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Suppose my game gets a huge background, which is larger than screen. My question is when the sprite of background is dragged or scrolled, how to make the rest of the sprites' position (like players and enemys) ajusted to follow the move of the background. plz someone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add all the sprites to a specific `CCNode` so that you are allowed to change its position. Since cocos2d manages everything as a hierarchy of nodes, everything contained inside that node will be moved too.

```
CCNode *sprites = [[CCNode alloc] init];

[sprites addChild:sprite1];
[sprites addChild:sprite2];

sprites.position = ccp(whatever);
```

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling in cocos2d

1.https://github.com/levilansing/cocos2d-ScrollNode

2.http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/code-vertical-scroll-layer-to-behave-like-uiscrollview/

3.http://www.sendspace.com/file/5luyht